# MSPointerDown event is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, events, window, surface

I added a function in MSPointerDown event in jquery. It is not working at IE of window tablet.

```
<div id="mytag" style="-ms-touch-action: none;"></div>

$('body').on('MSPointerDown', '#mytag', function(){alert('hi');});
```

How can I add this function to work well in IE of window tablet.

Comment: MSPonterDown is really an IE10 name, It is prefixless in IE11. I am not sure why it is not binding in jQuery. Have a look at my gesture library, http://DeepTissueJS.com. It might help you out.